# Can't run R on Heroku with RinRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r, heroku

R is running okay in development on my Rails 4.2.6 app, but I can't get it to run in production on Heroku with the RinRuby gem (2.0.3).  Heroku rejects an attempted push with the following errors (relevant parts of log):

```
-----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

    /app/tmp/buildpacks/        f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rinruby'.
Gem Load Error is: No such file or directory - R
ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
     !     Push failed
```

I didn't have problems deploying to Heroku before installing RinRuby.  I can successfully run

```
bundle exec rake -P command
```

against the app. I also tried placing

```
config.assets.compile =true
```

in the production environment, but that didn't solve the issue.

Don't know what's going on with the syntax errors; stumped on the RinRuby load error.  To deploy R in production, I have the following files in the root directory:

.buildpacks:

```
http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#cedar-14-chroot
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

init.r:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

While researching, I found a similar but unanswered post:  [Install error of Rinruby on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481108/install-error-of-rinruby-on-heroku)

What I'm I missing?  How do I fix?  More detail ... here's the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.2.4"

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rolify' 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-tablesorter'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.8.1'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.7.14'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 0.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jc-validates_timeliness'
gem 'validates_overlap'
gem 'time_difference'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.1.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'  # Amazon S3 cloud storage
gem 'chart-js-rails', '~> 0.0.9'
gem 'by_star', :git => "git://github.com/radar/by_star"
gem 'ransack'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin' # serves Faye to handle publishing/subscribing asynchronously
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11.1'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rinruby', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.3'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'figaro'  
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'seed_dump'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'rails_best_practices', require:false
  gem "letter_opener"                 
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rspec-rails'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.8.3'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I successfully installed R on Heroku for my Rails app. In an effort to help someone else who may need this information, here are the steps I took to solve the problem:

1. Uninstalled the RinRuby gem, and installed rootapp-rinruby (https://rubygems.org/gems/rootapp-rinruby), a more recent fork of the RinRuby gem.
2. Modifed the int.r file:

   ```
   my_packages = c("ggplot2")


   install_if_missing = function(p) {
     if (p %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) {
       install.packages(p, dependencies = TRUE)
     }
     else {
       cat(paste("Skipping already installed package:", p, "\n"))
     }
   }
   invisible(sapply(my_packages, install_if_missing))
   ```
3. Created a file called .r-version and put it in root directory with the following content:

   3.4.0
4. Added this R buildpack (http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#cedar-14-chroot) to Heroku

Now when I push, the Heroku log reports....

```
R 3.4.0 successfully installed (with init)
```

I hope this information helps someone. Good luck!

Comment: For me, replacing `gem 'rinruby'` with `gem 'rootapp-rinruby' ` solved it! - thanks for the question/answer!

Comment: This comment should be the accepted answer. Thanks @stevec!

Answer (score 0):

For improved visibility, placing [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807691/cant-run-r-on-heroku-with-rinruby/43826981?noredirect=1#comment95565726_43826981) as an answer:

In your `Gemfile`, replace:

```
gem 'rinruby'
```

with

```rb
gem 'rootapp-rinruby'
```